# Export unique values from QGIS layer column

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-2.18

I have a shapefile loaded into QGIS.When i apply filter i can quickly see all the unique values in that column. Is there a quick way to extract that for use in code? I know i could load the shapefile into a geo database and extract from there but for a single file that seems a lot of setup

Answer (score 2):

Vector layers have a uniqueValues function, which is available from Python:

```
v = iface.activeLayer()
idx = v.fieldNameIndex('your_column_name')
vals = v.uniqueValues(idx)
```

You can try it in the Python console to get the unique values from column 'your_column_name' of the active layer. The vals list contains all unique values (unsorted).

Comment: This worked for me perfectly. I had to adapt the `idx`-line though. `v = iface.activeLayer()
idx = v.fields().indexFromName('your_column_name')
vals = v.uniqueValues(idx)`

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of possible approaches you could use and here's three:

**Quick** (*and nasty* but effective): Open the dbf portion of the shapefile in Excel (or OpenOffice/Libre Office etc) and pull the unique values out and save as a CSV or something.  See [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2) for details.  It is not recommended to fiddle with the separate parts of of shapefile, but if you know what you're doing and/or make a copy of the dbf file first - you shouldn't come to any harm.

**Slightly less Quick** (and much *less nasty*): read the dbf in read-only mode from within the program that is going to use the values.  How you do this will depend entirely on the programming language you decide to use, so I can't go into details here, but GDAL libraries (available for Python, Java and C++) will help.

**Another option** (no quicker than your own suggestion but less setup): Load your shapefile into SpatialLite and use the db functions to pull out the unique vales.